# How to print a '%' sign in a html string using PHP

Tags: php, html

I've the following code in my PHP file:

```html
      echo"  <td width='38%' valign='top' bgcolor='lightgray'><textarea  rows='5' cols='100%' >" . $row['Oefeningen'] .</textarea></td>"
```

This all works fine except for the width of the textarea. The `100%` transforms into `100`, so the % character seems to be ignored.
How to format the string so that the `%` sign is included?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  That's not how the `cols` attribute works.  This has nothing to do with PHP, it's just the browser trying to make sense of otherwise invalid HTML.

[`cols` expects a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).  When the browser sees `100%` it interprets it as `100`, which is the closest thing it can find to a number in that value.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `cols` attribute and style the `textarea` instead:

```
echo "<td width='38%' valign='top' bgcolor='lightgray'><textarea rows='5' style='width:100%' >" . $row['Oefeningen'] . "</textarea></td>";
```

I've used inline CSS but it'd be better to put it in an external CSS file.